# Can I use a single ChatGPT-3 API key for multiple projects simultaneously?

Tags: chatgpt-api, gpt-4

I am a new programmer in college and I am trying to learn how to use API keys. I am currently using the ChatGPT-3 API for my Siri personal assistant project, and it's been working well for me so far.

Now, I am developing another application - a bot that can utilize my resume to automatically generate cover letters, and reach out to talent acquisition teams.

Can I use the same ChatGPT-3 API key for both projects simultaneously? Are there any limitations or issues I should be aware of while using a single API key for multiple projects?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the same API key for multiple projects.

But you can only fine-tune one model per API key at a time. If you want to fine-tune multiple models, you should create a new API key and run the second model with the new key.
You may find [this](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/few-things-know-before-using-free-gpt3-apis-khushal-modi?trk=articles_directory) helpful.

Also make sure to optimise your prompts to efficiently use your tokens, and also to get structured outputs. You may find [Promptify](https://github.com/promptslab/Promptify) helpful in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You should also consider security. Sharing API key across multiple projects means if the key is leaked, every projects needs to be updated to use a new key. This is the age-old security vs convenience tradeoff. I'd say if the projects are not deployed publicly, sharing is fine.